# Erro de carregar URL do facebook PHP SDK, ao efetuar login

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, facebook-sdk

A minha função de login encontra-se assim no `Laravel`

```
public function loginFacebook(){
    $fb = new Facebook([
        'app_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
        ]);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    $permissions = ["pages_show_list", "manage_pages", "pages_messaging", "pages_messaging_phone_number", "pages_messaging_subscriptions", "public_profile", "email"]; // Optional permissions
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://teste.dev.br/login/facebook/callback', $permissions);

    echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
}
```

E nas configurações do app está com o domínio configurado conforme imagens abaixo:

[image: Dominio do app]

E o do URL do site.

[image: URL do site]

Porém quando rodo, dispara o seguinte erro no `Facebook`

> Não é possível carregar a URL: O domínio dessa URL não está incluído nos domínios do aplicativo. Para poder carregar essa URL, adicione todos os domínios e subdomínios ao campo Domínios do aplicativo nas configurações do aplicativo.

O que pode estar ocorrendo?

Comment: Putz eu sofri com isso ai hein, o erro é genérico, pode ser várias coisas, mas pelos seus prints, parece que falta a url do callback, pra onde ele vai retornar após o login.

Comment: Além de configurar estas informações básicas, você precisa configurar o oauth, no painel esquerdo tem produtos, clica ali e segue os passos para ativar o oauth... Dentro das configurações dele vai ter a opção de adicionar os callbacks

Comment: @edsonalves, onde fica localizado essa opção dos oauth? não estou encontrando

Comment: Vc tem que adicionar um produto. No canto esquerdo tem um +(mais) em produtos. Nas opções de produto vai ter oauth